# Cache Controls loaded at Runtime

Tags: c#, loadcontrol

My question is similar to [Access to PartialCachingControl.CachedControl before Add it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684191/access-to-partialcachingcontrol-cachedcontrol-before-add-it) but since i cannot add the control to page before setting control attributes im still having problems

I have a UserControl with a public property called "Content" which i would like to cache.  On the UserControl ive added:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="none"  %>
```

Before adding the Cache Attribute i used to load the controls as followed

```
 public static Control DocumentWidget (System.Web.UI.Page currentPage, Comito.LokalPortalen.Domain.Entity.CMS.Content.Content content)
 {
    Comito.LokalPortalen.FrontEndShared.Controls.Document.Widget documentWidget = (FrontEndShared.Controls.Document.Widget)currentPage.LoadControl("/FrontEndShared/Controls/Document/Widget.ascx");
    if (documentWidget != null)
     {
        documentWidget.Content = content;
        return documentWidget;
     }
        return null;
}
```

I would now like to do something like :

```
PartialCachingControl documentWidget = (PartialCachingControl)currentPage.LoadControl("/FrontEndShared/Controls/Document/Widget.ascx");
if (documentWidget != null)
{
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo cmsContent = documentWidget.GetType().GetProperty("Content");
    documentWidget.Content = content;
    return documentWidget;
}
```

Which fails with "PartialCachingControl  doesnt contain a definition for "Content"

or like the solution supposed in [Access to PartialCachingControl.CachedControl before Add it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684191/access-to-partialcachingcontrol-cachedcontrol-before-add-it) but since i cant add the control before setting attributes this doesnt Work.

Any solution